# Can you help on Angular data-ng-repeat: not getting Data from mySQL data base

Tags: angularjs

This is my configuration.jsp page code:-this is section where i am using angular data-ng-repeat tag

```
    <tbody id="all">
    <tr data-ng-repeat="config in listConfiguration">
    <td>{{ config.city }}</td>
    <td>{{ config.locality }}</td>**strong text**
    <td>{{ config.controller }}</td>
    <td class="text-navy">{{ config.phase }}</td>
    <td>{{ config.onoff_type }}</td>
    <td class="text-navy">{{ config.config_type }}</td>
    <td>{{ config.on_time }}</td>
    <td>{{ config.off_time }}</td>
    <td>{{ config.last_execution }}</td>
    <td>{{ config.next_execution }}</td>                                            
    </tr>                   
    </tbody>
```

This is REST Controller code for connecting database:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/configurenew", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView configurenew() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    System.out.println("configurenew Method");
    List<ConfigDB> listConfiguration = loginDAO.configurationDetails();
    model.addObject("listConfiguration", listConfiguration);
    model.setViewName("configuration");
    return model;
```

Rest Controller return this list Object "listConfiguration" but I am unable to get this List object value in   Jsp page.

can you look this section where i am doing wrong code.

Comment: This is REST Controller code for connecting database:
        
         List listConfiguration = (List) loginDAO.configurationDetails();
          model.addObject("listConfiguration", listConfiguration);
          model.setViewName("configuration");
          return model;          
                  
        
         This code is working fine when i am using this
         <c:forEach var="configuration" items="${listConfiguration}"
        varStatus="status"> that mean my data is correct from database.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41251410/edit) the question to add additional code. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: I am not getting what you want say this comments.

Comment: Please add your angular controller's code to your question

Comment: <div class="wrapper" data-ng-controller="confCtrl as ctrl">

Comment: 'use strict';

var AppConfigure = angular.module('configure',
  [ 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngTagsInput' ]);
// Declaration of controller function.
var configCtrl = function($log, $scope, $interval, ConfigureService) {

Comment: update your question, dont place it in the comments

Comment: i have updated again Question.